# Can I leave the airport in London for a city tour?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, london

I am an Indian and will be transiting through London coming from the US, going to New Delhi. I have a nine hour stop over in London. I am a Schengen visa holder.

Will I be allowed to leave the airport to visit the city?

Comment: You may qualify for Transit Without Visa in the UK if you have a visa or residence permit for the US -- at least it won't hurt to line up for immigration and ask nicely. The worst that can happen is that you'll be sent back airside to bide your time there instead.

Answer (score 3):

The United Kingdom is not part of the Schengen area. You need a visitor visa to the UK.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to arrange a visa in advance (there is no "visa on arrival" in the UK). To find out exactly what kind of visa you need, follow this simple wizard on https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa

It will provide you the most accurate information, as it is directly managed by the UK government.